# Search and cancel notification with Tasker

Tags: notifications, 4.2-jelly-bean, tasker, whatsapp-messenger

I'm looking for a way to search for (by text) and cancel a notification that wasn't created by Tasker with it.

I know there's an option to cancel notifications which were created by Tasker but I want to cancel some notifications of WhatsApp.

Comment: Which version of OS you are using?

Comment: Android 4.2 Jelly Bean.

Comment: Do you want to cancel all notifications from WhatsApp messenger?

Comment: no only those from a specific group.